# JNI - Disconnected from the target VM, during the execution of native code

Tags: c#, java, c++, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I'm getting an error with a Java exception while executing my program. Though java catches the exception it continues the execution of native code without giving the intended result.

here is the native code that I guess something wrong with it :-

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^ processImages(unsigned char* frontImage, unsigned char* backImage);
jbyteArray convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(JNIEnv *env,array<unsigned char>^ inputArray);
unsigned char* convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(JNIEnv *env, jbyteArray inImage);

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_me_NativeCaller_processImages
(JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jbyteArray front, jbyteArray back){
    unsigned char* frontBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, front);
    unsigned char* backBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, back);

    jbyteArray intermediateArray1 = convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(env,(array<unsigned char>^)returnedValue[0]);
    jbyteArray intermediateArray2 = convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(env,(array<unsigned char>^)returnedValue[1]);

    int aLen1 = strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&intermediateArray1));
    int aLen2 = strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&intermediateArray2));

    jbyteArray finalArray = env->NewByteArray(2);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,0,1,(jbyte*)&intermediateArray1); 
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,1,2,(jbyte*)&intermediateArray2);
    return static_cast<jobject>(finalArray);
}

/*takes an array<unsigned char>^ as input and convert it into a jbyteArray*/
jbyteArray convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(JNIEnv *env,array<unsigned char>^ inputArray){
    int aLen = strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&inputArray));
    jbyteArray intermediateArray = env->NewByteArray(aLen);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(intermediateArray,0,aLen,(jbyte*)&inputArray);
    return intermediateArray;
}
```

to be precise I think the way I convert manged unsigned char into jbyteArray is not correct.

can someone show me where did I go wrong, and a possible way to overcome this problem.

Comment: `array<unsigned char>^ inputArray`  What is that "^" thing doing there?

Comment: I'm not much clear about it. I found it in a sample code.

Comment: Well, that is not "traditional" C++ code.  It looks like that C++/CLI syntax.  You should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Did you check that the values of aLen1 and aLen2 are reasonable?  Everywhere where you do `&somearray` looks suspicious to me.  It more than likely should be just `somearray`.

Comment: apparently it's bit confusing. but it's syntactically correct I guess. Maybe because of I have misused a reference.

Comment: It may be syntactically correct, but seems to be wrong.  The jbyteArray is already a pointer, and you're taking the address of a pointer, which is not correct in terms of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: indeed, I have converted an address of unsigned char array into a jbyte pointer. This might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks incorrect:

```
    jbyteArray intermediateArray1 = convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(env,(array<unsigned char>^)returnedValue[0]);
    jbyteArray intermediateArray2 = convertUnsignedCharIntoJByteArray(env,(array<unsigned char>^)returnedValue[1]);

    //...

    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,0,1,(jbyte*)&intermediateArray1); 
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,1,2,(jbyte*)&intermediateArray2);
```

Not familiar with C++/CLI syntax using that "^" stuff, I'm focusing on jbyteArray and the SetByteArrayRegion() call.  A jbyteArray is an alias for a pointer.  Given that, the calls to SetByteArrayRegion() are not correct.  It should be:

```
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,0,1,(jbyte*)intermediateArray1); 
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(finalArray,1,2,(jbyte*)intermediateArray2);
```

You may also check your other usages of `&array` in other parts of your code.  Again, I'm not familiar with the nuances of the "^" syntax, but have used traditional C++ to implement JNI code.